# Swift version required by a Pod?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods

I am trying to install a Pod in my IOS/iPhone project using Xcode 9.3.1.

My target app is configured to use Swift 3.3.

After adding the following line to my podfile...

> pod 'Concorde'

I ran...

> pod install

The pod installed normally. However, upon compilation, I receive a mess of compiler warnings and errors like "NSUrlResponse was obsoleted in Swift 3". It seems the Swift version I have (3.3) is too new.

The Swift version configured for the build target is also 3.3.

[image]

It looks like an older Swift is required for this Pod. However, is there a simple way to determine which Swift version is required for the pod?

I checked the [CocoaPods.org web site](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Concorde) and the page does not show the Swift version required for the library.

I also checked the podspec, where I expected to find that version number requirement.

Comment: how about reading the pod repo description on github ?

Comment: I happen to see a commit "Swift 4 Update" at https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde, but was looking for a more general and clear identifier. Is "pod repo description" a "thing"?

Comment: you could  try  terminal command : pod try "name of the pod" and check it inside xcode

Comment: why not using other pod, like https://cocoapods.org/pods/Kingfisher

Comment: Ok, what version of swift does Kingfisher require? (It's the same question). I'd like to use the library I want to use (I have my reasons - you know how it is...).

Comment: "pod try" gives me "invalid byte sequence" and a mess of other errors.

Comment: you can check on the repo but for Kingfisher i think its up to date since its really popular

Comment: Such is the fate of abandoned pods. This one was last updated in 2016 so it was probably written in Swift 2 or 3. You can clone it and upgrade it to Swift 4 yourself.

Comment: that means the same pod has a problem or don't  have an example to try, and that indicates that its not that good for my personal view

Comment: also as @CodeDifferent you can always edit it and update it to swift 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try terminal command,

```
pod try "pod name"
```

this will clone the repo automatically for you to test the framework on the fly 
there you can check out whatever you need.

Plus reading the description on GitHub helps too

Also i recommend using highly popular pods, as they tempt to be more stable.

read the reviews about the framework, and try to find other alternatives for it.

New update: You can try to preview `.podspec` file inside the Repo on github sometimes you can find the Swift Version of that Pod  example : [here](https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser/blob/master/SKPhotoBrowser.podspec)

Comment: Getting a bunch of errors with that. In this case I'm trying to find a library which supports progressive downloads. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/554, which makes Concorde a simpler solution.

Comment: good luck with that, but your question was on how to check the swift version and make sure and i think this answers it ^_^ good luck with haunting something that works for you

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's correct - I don't want to change libraries. But I'm still not seeing an answer for my question. Switching libraries is a bit of a distraction, though perhaps it will work.

Comment: well can you mark me as correct and vote me up that would help me a lot thanks and good luck sir @CharlieDalsass

Comment: "Swift version required for the library." the only way to 100% be sure is by pod try 
so i thought this was your question, and you can always clone it and check for your self remember this is open source so . sometimes things are not 100% accurate when it comes to pods

Comment: My research is indicating that it doesn't exist as well. One would think that cocoapods.org would have that as an official dependency. Perhaps I'll suggest that to them. (Maybe make another answer "it doesn't exist".) ;)

Comment: could be, thank you for the note tho, i'll put more work on my answers in the future  where i understand exactly what the poster want to hear  instead of explaining something. i hope i was useful in any case

Comment: ill keep it as is, perhaps someone come across and learn new thing or two about pods and command

Comment: updated the answer check the new answer please thank you @CharlieDalsass

Comment: Adding to the podspec appears to be the correct way to find Swift version. There seems to be some ambiguity in general, but you just have to hope they defined it in one of the places. Would be good if they added it to cocoapods.org.